# SQL Oracle Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having problem with simple trigger command. This trigger operation will insert value into table **address_rit** when a person who studies at RIT is inserted into table **person**. Here's the syntax for the trigger command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER addr
AFTER INSERT ON person
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.college = 'RIT')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO address_rit (name, address, state) 
VALUES (NEW.name, NEW.address, (SELECT name FROM states WHERE NEW.statecode = states.statecode));
END;
/
```

The trigger is compiled but with warning. However, further inspection shows that the trigger actually has error. Here's the error from the compilation.

```
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored   ERROR
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here  ERROR
```

I'm pretty sure the error is just a syntax error, but I just can't find any solution. Let me know if I need to add more detail. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The problem is that you're using `values` and `select` at the same time... but conrad's answer is the way to go. Look at the [`insert` syntax](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php) for more information.

Comment: @Ben - You can have a scalar subquery in an `INSERT ... VALUES` statement.  It's a bit quirky but it's valid syntax.

Comment: @JustinCave, well you learn something new every day... :-) I always thought it was illegal; though I won't be doing it often...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a minimum, you need a colon before `NEW`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER addr
  AFTER INSERT ON person
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.college = 'RIT')
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO address_rit (name, address, state) 
    VALUES (:NEW.name, 
            :NEW.address, 
            (SELECT name 
               FROM states 
              WHERE :NEW.statecode = states.statecode));
END;
/
```

I'm also assuming that the query against the `STATES` table is always going to return exactly 1 row.  If the database is properly normalized, though, I would expect that all the tables would have a `STATECODE` column rather than a `STATE` column and that there would be foreign keys between both `PERSON` and `ADDRESS_RIT` that reference the `STATECODE` column in `STATES`.  But, if the database is properly normalized, I would also expect that you wouldn't have an `ADDRESS_RIT` table that duplicated the data in `PERSON`.  Instead, `ADDRESS_RIT` really ought to be a view on the `PERSON` table.

Comment: That works! The problem is the binding NEW. I've read several article about trigger and I am confused on how to use the NEW binding. Thanks a lot!